# show data at DIV after use .focus() in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, setfocus

Lets say i have a form like:

```
<select id="model"/>
<input type="text" id="serial"/>
<label>Packing <div id="packing" name="packing"></div></label>
<br/>
<input id="pack1" type="radio" class="pack" name="pack" value="OK" />OK
<input id="pack2" type="radio" class="pack" name="pack" value="NG" />NG
i'm using barcode scanner for input `serial`, i want do like this:
```

1. choose `model` at dropdown list
2. after `model` choosen, set focus into `#serial` so it can makes data show at textfield
3. data after scan show inside textfield
4. after textfield are filled, show some data from DB inside the `DIV`

this is what i have got:

```
$("#model").click(function() {
          var data=$("#model").val();
          $("submit input:text.eq(0)").focus();
          var str=data;
          var matches=str.match(/[TEJUG2]\D*D/i);

          $.ajax({
                   type:"post",
                   url:"process1.php",
                   data:"packing="+matches+"&action=packcond",
                   cache:false,
                   async:false,
                   success: function(res){
                                    $('#value').replaceWith(
                                          "<div id='value'><h6>" + res + "</h6></div>"
                                          );
                                    }
                   });
          });
```

but i think this not resolve the problem.can you help me? :-)

Comment: I'm confusing with your html structure. input inside select , div inside label, td?

Comment: we can put some div inside label.for another i have edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#model").change(function() {
                  $('#serial').focus();
                  });

$('#serial').change(function(){
                  var data=$("#model").val();
                  var str=data;
                  var matches=str.match(/[TEJUG2]\D*D/i);

                  $.ajax({
                          type:"post",
                          url:"process1.php",
                          data:"packing="+matches+"&action=packcond",
                          cache:false,
                          async:false,
                          success: function(res){
                                          $('#value').replaceWith(
                                          "<div id='value'><h6>" + res + "</h6></div>"
                                          );
                                      }
                          });
                  });
```