# How to show entered data in other div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to enter data one by one and after hit **ADD BUTTON** data should be added and shown to other div. I am using **html**,**css** and **javascrit**.
same like **shopping sites** i.e. One by one we add product and it appears in **cart**.

I am new to web designing, please help.

Comment: Please show us your Javascript/CSS/HTML

Comment: See related questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075450/show-data-at-div-after-use-focus-in-jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WdcTK/30/)

Html:

```
<a href="#" class="design_button add">Click here to add Product</a>
<div id="this_div_contains_settings"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
   var number = 1;
   $('a.add').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#this_div_contains_settings').append('<div id="settings'+number+'">Product Item.<a href="#" class="design_button">Remove this Product</a></div>');
      number++;
   });
   $('#this_div_contains_settings').on('click','a.design_button', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: where is css classes defined? class="design_button" and class="design_button add" ?

Comment: I am glad it helps u :) currently no css rules are applied for these classes you can use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This could be first demo to be used to learn

```
<div id="console"></div>
<input id="input" type="text">

<button id="trigger">Click me!</button>

<script>
document.getElementsById("trigger").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("console").innnerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
}

</script>
```